# Give hover effect reflecting the upper class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Now this is want there are 2 col i have given border-bottom type on the main div width 50% so it only cover the first part now this is what i want , when i hovers the second col the :hover should trigger the upper class and move margin -left with 50% or say float:right and vice versa

```css
.special-row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.special-row:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #0577ad;
  height: 1px;
}

.special-row .hover-2:hover>.special-row:after {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.special-row .hover-1:hover>.special-row:after {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row special-row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 hover-1">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 hover-2">
    Two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you wish to do? Would you like a border under the element which is being hovered, or is it the opposite?

Comment: @Chri.s There are 2 div placed side by side i want a hover effect below each div and also :active which ever is selected

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to reach the parent class in CSS. You can only go deeper. I recreated the hover effect another way: https://jsfiddle.net/6ty09ja2/5/

Comment: As i'm not quite sure whether you want a border active at the first div when not hovering, or only show the border on hover, i also recreated a little example in the fiddle below, with the border shown at the first div from start: https://jsfiddle.net/sx2vmf2s/

Comment: what if i want a default active class and after clicking other class the border bottom moves with a smooth transition to the other div is that possible ? @SebastianMuszyński

Comment: I don't think it's possible with pure CSS. Here is a sample solution using some JS & jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/6ty09ja2/8/

Comment: thanks bro you saved my day @SebastianMuszyński